# Why does my profile picture keep changing?

Tags: support

Why does my profile picture keep changing?  Is this a bug?
And why can't I change it back?
There's only ever 1 default image to choose from, even though I know there are many different default pictures.
Does anyone know how I can change it back?
Thanks,

Comment: P.S. I uploaded a different picture because I didn't like the new default image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a Meta.SO post, [Unexpectedly changing identicon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204523/172958)

> Since recently we are salting creation of hashes for generating identicons for users that do not have a gravatar account. This is because there were some concerns that the gravatar identicon urls leak email addresses.
>
> If you're so attached to your old identicon register with gravatar, and use your identicon as the profile image.

If you really want, you can download your [old identicon](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4d5396c24560f18b7b30da3727478440?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) and manually upload it.